# wx python 3.0.2 classic 'CheckListBox' object has no attribute 'GetItemHeight'

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

Investigating porting my wx 2.8 python app to wx 3.0.2 classic (it's about time) and run into this hurdle. Apparently the GetItemHeight is not part of CheckListBox class anymore:

```
bash\basher\patcher_dialog.py:519: wxPyDeprecationWarning: Accessing deprecated property. 
  mouseItem = (event.m_y/self.gPatchers.GetItemHeight() +
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bash\basher\patcher_dialog.py", line 519, in OnMouse
    mouseItem = (event.m_y/self.gPatchers.GetItemHeight() +
AttributeError: 'CheckListBox' object has no attribute 'GetItemHeight'
```

People were using them to get the item hovered upon in a mouse event handler (gPatchers below is a `wx.CheckListBox`):

```
def OnMouse(self,event):
    if event.Moving():
        mouseItem = (event.m_y/self.gPatchers.GetItemHeight() +
            self.gPatchers.GetScrollPos(wx.VERTICAL))
        if mouseItem != self.mouseItem:
            self.mouseItem = mouseItem
            self.MouseEnteredItem(mouseItem)
    elif event.Leaving():
        self.gTipText.SetLabel(self.defaultTipText)
        self.mouseItem = -1
    event.Skip()
```

So how do I achieve this in wx python 3.0.2 ?

**EDIT:** cross posted in the wx-users mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/mMYr-51sE4s

Comment: Plus one for proper cross-posting to wxpython-users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [`HitTest`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.ListBox.html#wx.ListBox.HitTest) from the underlying class `ListBox` to find which item is at the given x/y coordinate. Item is the `int` index of list element. The documentation is for wxPython phoenix, but works identical under wxPython MSW classic 3.0.2.

```
    # lb is a wx.(Check)ListBox instance
    lb.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouse)

def OnMouse(self, evt):
    obj = evt.GetEventObject()
    x, y = evt.GetPosition()
    if isinstance(obj, wx.ListBox):
        item = obj.HitTest(wx.Point(x, y))
        # do something with item index information
```

Comment: Haha - you know what, I already figured out and was ready to post my answer but thanks for getting me rid of the chore. A shame there is no note on which method should replace it.

Answer (score -1):

## Hi you can try the following trick to do this.

> I couldn't try this with your code but it is also the way you can find the height of CheckListBox

```
 self.gPatchers.GetClientRect()[3]
```

> It will return the height in pixel.
> GetClientRect() method will return tuple of 4 value (x,y,width,height)

Comment: Off topic - not interested in the height of the control but the height of its _items_